# How can I access an angular route directly in the Browser?

Tags: angular, express, angular-routing, angular-router

Hello I am having issues with express rendering some routes. When I visit the website **example.com**, everything works as it should.

But, when i visit a route like **example.com/login**. I get an error stating **Cannot get /login**. So I went and edited the Express file to Include the route now it's a different error. I get that angular is SPA but there has to be a way. A user will very likely use a direct path to a page.

There are question out there but none has a solution it seems.

Still I can't find a suitable solution.

This is the Express file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("dist/website"));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/login');
 });

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/login');
 });


app.listen(4200);
```

**This is the App.routing**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'  },
  { path: '**',   redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is another error

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
    at /usr/app/index.js:17:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/usr/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
```

Comment: More than likely you need to redirect all requests to the index.html file. You have to do that for all SPA web pages because index.html is the only actual navigable file on the server, the others are just filler code swapped in through JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to go and get that to work. I thought it was an Angular issue. Turns out it is an express issue.

Answer (score 0):

As @MylesMorrone mentioned the routes need to get redirected. This takes a bit of planning - If you are to do so you should know of all possible routes in your app.

Get in the express file and do this

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("dist/website"));


app.all('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('example.com/');
 });

app.all('/login', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('https://example.com/#/login');
 });


app.listen(4200);
```

The * route routes every none existent route back to the homepage. So only use when you don't have other routes you would like to access directly.

You have to ensure that you use the **Hash** sign in the domain name.